# How to change icon of app in android studio ? I replaced the mipmap folder by new ic_launcher but still not showing the icon i set

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I replaced the mipmap folder by new ic_launcher folder  but still not showing the icon I set,
in manifest file the icon is set to ic_launcher `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` but still the old logo is showing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to change the app icon changed a long time ago. In android studio goto

```
File > New > Image Asset
```

Now you will be able to create a new icon for your app.

Answer (score -1):

you need to change that name  with your icon name

```
android:icon="@mipmap/{your icon name}.png
```